How do I add a global variable to a singular Storybook doc file?
I want to generate a dynamic piece of code that can be copied based on a setting that is changed in the toolbar. Changing the setting in the toolbar will change the code that the user can copy.
I am able to accomplish this with a story, but I want it to just be an MDX file. I want it to be a singular doc file that is not nested within a story. The only variable I am using is the one from the toolbar. Is this possible?
Maybe I am overcomplicating this, but I want something like this: https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-design-token
^ This is able to exist in solely an MDX file at a high level. I'm looking for the same functionality.
